# Linear Differential Equation Plotting around Critical Point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, graphing-functions

Consider this System:

$$
   X'= \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & -5  \\
    1 & -3
    \end{pmatrix} X
$$
and
$$
   X= \begin{pmatrix}
     x\\
     y   
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

I want to get an approximation of phase plot (around  $(0,0)$) and plot of each $x$ and $y$ in terms of $t$. note that I don't want to use software or any calculator and I want to use easy mathematical and numerical ways to approximate the shape.

For eigenvalues, I got $\lambda =\pm i - 1 $. because of $-1$ the $(0,0)$ point is asymptotically stable and a spiral point. For drawing $y_x$ plot (phase plane), I just plot some point on the equation and found some X' and drawed that with the direction towards $(0,0)$. But I don't know how to plot $x$ and $y$ in terms of $t$ (time). What should I do?

Comment: Factor each one into the product of an exponential and a sinusoid. The exponential bounds the oscillations of the sinusoid.